# How to link a measure variable in a supervision to a VBA code?

Tags: vba, variables, scada

I'm currently in an Internship where i'm supposed to bring some modifications and upgrades to an already functioning SCADA in Pcvue.

One of my mission is to be able to modify an already existing measure variable directly into the supervision while it's active.

I managed to code a working inputBox via VBA  but the problem i'm left with is that i don't know how to assign the number i write directly to the already existing measure variable.

Do you guys have any idea how to code this?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any vba code and inputbox to enter a value. Use simply a standard Send animation with an internal variable.